# ListPlot3D and plotting a 3 dimensional array

Tags: plotting

I have a 3D array of the form:

```
{{{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3}...}}}
```

and `ListPlot3D` only accepts data of form:

```
{{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3}...}.
```

Is there any way I can convert from one to the other?

Comment: [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your initial list looks like this:

```
lis = {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}}
```

You can remove the outer list with **Flatten**:

```
Flatten[lis,1]
```

Results in:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}
```

OR

You could replace the outer containing list with the actual function using apply:

```
ListPlot3D @@ {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}}
```

Which is equivalent to,

```
Apply[ListPlot3D , {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}}]
```

Comment: ...or `{{{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3}...}}}[[1]]`.